# Is it safe to modify RVO values within an RAII construct?

Tags: c++, destructor, raii, copy-elision, rvo

Consider the following program:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class RvoObj {
  public:
    RvoObj(int x) : x_{x} {}
    RvoObj(const RvoObj& obj) : x_{obj.x_} { std::cout << "copied\n"; }
    RvoObj(RvoObj&& obj) : x_{obj.x_} { std::cout << "moved\n"; }

    int x() const { return x_; }
    void set_x(int x) { x_ = x; }

  private:
    int x_;
};

class Finally {
  public:
    Finally(std::function<void()> f) : f_{f} {}
    ~Finally() { f_(); }

  private:
    std::function<void()> f_;
};

RvoObj BuildRvoObj() {
    RvoObj obj{3};
    Finally run{[&obj]() { obj.set_x(5); }};
    return obj;
}

int main() {
    auto obj = BuildRvoObj();
    std::cout << obj.x() << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Both clang and gcc ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3e616bb8e7c6118)) output `5` without invoking the copy or move constructors.

Is this behavior well-defined and guaranteed by the C++17 standard?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54566080/9305398

Comment: "*now that copy-elision is required*" That's [not how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38043447/734069). There is no guaranteed elision in your code.

Comment: What terminology should I use to describe the behavior observed in the demo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: due to NRVO, the output of the program may be either `3` or `5`. Both are valid.

---

For background, see first:

- [in C++ which happens first, the copy of a return object or local object's destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33150508/in-c-which-happens-first-the-copy-of-a-return-object-or-local-objects-destru)
- [What are copy elision and return value optimization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Guideline:

- *Avoid destructors that modify return values.*

For example, when we see the following pattern:

```
T f() {
    T ret;
    A a(ret);   // or similar
    return ret;
}
```

We need to ask ourselves: does `A::~A()` modify our return value somehow? If yes, then our program most likely has a bug.

For example:

- A type that prints the return value on destruction is fine.
- A type that computes the return value on destruction is *not* fine.

<sub>*[From https://stackoverflow.com/a/54566080/9305398 ]*</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Copy elision only permits an implementation to remove the presence of the object being generated by a function. That is, it can remove the copy from `obj` to the return value object of `foo` and the destructor of `obj`. However, the implementation can't change anything else.

The copy to the return value would happen before destructors for local objects in the function are called. And the destructor of `obj` would happen after the destructor of `run`, because destructors for automatic variables are executed in reverse-order of their construction.

This means that it is safe for `run` to access `obj` in its destructor. Whether the object denoted by `obj` is destroyed after `run` completes or not does not change this fact.

***However***, there is one problem. See, `return <variable_name>;` for a local variable is required to invoke a *move* operation. In your case, moving from `RvoObj` is the same as copying from it. So for your specific code, it'll be fine.

But if `RvoObj` were, for example, `unique_ptr<T>`, you'd be in trouble. Why? Because the move operation to the return value happens *before destructors for local variables are called*. So in this case `obj` will be in the moved-from state, which for `unique_ptr` means that it's empty.

That's bad.

If the move is elided, then there's no problem. But since elision is not required, there is potentially a problem, since your code will behave differently based on whether elision happens or not. Which is implementation-defined.

So generally speaking, it's best not to have destructors rely on the existence of local variables that you're returning.

---

The above purely relates to your question about *undefined behavior*. It isn't UB to do something that changes behavior based on whether elision happens or not. The standard defines that one or the other will happen.

However, you cannot and should not *rely upon it*.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! "There is potentially a problem since your code will behave differently based on whether elision happens or not" — so then I can assume the code is always safe in C++17?

Comment: I don't think the real question is just "will this invoke UB?" but also "is this guaranteed to print `5`?" I think @OP assumed that if it's not UB the value won't change on the compiler's whim, but that is not the case. Sticking to the standard, NVRO is not guaranteed, so I believe this code is allowed to print *either* `3` or `5`. It's guaranteed not to be UB but also not totally determined.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez: Your post is tagged c++17, so I answered it relative to its tag.

Comment: @BrianRodriguez If you mean "will this code always print `5` in C++17?" that's a no. The kind of elision guaranteed in C++17 is not the kind of elision you need.

Comment: @HTNW could you elaborate more on that (maybe in an answer)?

Comment: I've clarified my question to be more explicit about what I was aiming to learn.